# как правельно обработать promise у fetch JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Добрый день дорогие друзья, у меня есть функция которая делает ajax запрос 
в файле А

```
export function ajax() {
    return fetch(`http://example.com/api/events`)
        .then(
            function (response) {
                response.json().then(function (data) {
                    return data;
                });
            }
        )
}
```

В файле Б я ее вызываю

```
console.log(ajax());
```

но она возвращает promise
Как мне получить ответ от функции?

Comment: Скорее всего как-то так: `ajax().then((answer) => {console.log(answer)})`

Comment: @smellyshovel, в данном случае это не сработает

Comment: @Grundy а почему?

Comment: @smellyshovel, не хватает `return`

Comment: @Grundy на 5-ой строчке?

Comment: Причем тут дубликат? - в react работают (см тэк) там нет await

Comment: @ff.0xff, а разве в дубликате только про await написано?